# how to get param in my directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I write template for my directive, template.html:

```
<ul><span>{{name}}</span>
   <li ng-repeat="value in values">
</ul>
```

Plug directive like:

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
   return{
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
   };
});
```

I have some js object looks like:

```
const myObj:{
    name:"MyObjName",
    values:["val1","val2","val3","val4"]
}
```

Tell me please how can I send to my template my object so it will render directive like I want?? 
In index html it looks like `<div my-dir="{{myObj}}"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.directive('myDir', function(){
   return{
    scope: {
      myDir: "="
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
   };
});

<ul><span>{{myDir.name}}</span>
   <li ng-repeat="value in myDir.values"></li>
</ul>
```

Usage:

```
<div my-dir="myObj"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the object to directives scope and it'll be available in your template. Just use

```
 app.directive('myDir', function(){
   return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
       'myDir': '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
   };
});
```

and then you can pass the object the way you want to the directive.

```
<div my-dir="myObj"></div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Can't understand why it doesn't work. Directive works fine and in DOM I see my template, but without any data from myObj.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Since you are passing $scope model rather than a string,  '@' should be replaced with ' =' and pass the object directly. Working Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/BPt0NU?p=preview. Sorry., I just didn't noticed it first time.

Comment: In plnkr that I write before I use '@' and my-dir="{{myObj}}". But that doesn't work. I've already fixed code using string and '=', but I will be appreciate you if you explain me why my example in plnkr doesn't work.

Comment: If you pass an object like `{{myDir}}`, *interpolation*, it is binded to the directive's scope as a string, and in your template it will be available as a string.  In your plunkr, `myDir` was actually available in the directive's template as a string and not an object and hence ng-repeat was not working. And '@' was changed to '=' because '@' is used for string binding and '=' for two way model binding.

Comment: Understood!) Thanks for the explanation!!

Answer (score -1):

in class declare

```
public myObj: any;
```

In constructor set

```
this.myObj={
    name:"MyObjName",
    values:["val1","val2","val3","val4"]
};
```

In template

```
<div [my-dir]="myObj"></div>
```

Comment: are you sure this will work in angularJS? public `myObj: any` - as I understand its typescript, no?